# Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k(\frac{k}{k+1})^k$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k(\frac{k}{k+1})^k.$$Does it converge? Does it converge absolutely?

Now $$\lim_{k\to\infty}|(-1)^k(\frac{k}{k+1})^k|=...=\frac{1}{e}\neq0.$$ Thus the series isn't absolutely convergent. I cannot apply the Leibniz theorem, because $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\frac{k}{k+1})^k=\frac{1}{e}\neq0.$

Comment: The terms of the series do not converge to zero, so the series cannot converge.

Comment: Does $\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)^k$ converge to zero?

Comment: A necessary condition of the convergence is that the general term of the series converges to 0.

Comment: I have edited the problem statement.

Comment: Yes it converges but not in classic sense, this is same convergence as $1-1+1-1+1- \cdots = \frac{1}{2}$ .

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Does

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)^k=0\;\;?$$

Comment: No. It is $\pm \frac{1}{e}$, right?

Comment: @1likeMaths And thus **the limit** doesn't even exist...and the series doesn't converge. Period. Not absolutely, conditionally...it does *not* converge.